# How to change JFrame icon

Tags: java, swing, jframe, icons

I have a `JFrame` that displays a Java icon on the title bar (left corner).
I want to change that icon to my custom icon. How should I do it?

Comment: I bet that in the most cases those people have not even heard of the API yet. Probably the best solution in cases like this is to provide a link to the API with the answer.

Answer (score 192, accepted):

Create a new `ImageIcon` object like this:

```
ImageIcon img = new ImageIcon(pathToFileOnDisk);
```

Then set it to your `JFrame` with [`setIconImage()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JFrame.html#setIconImage-java.awt.Image-):

```
myFrame.setIconImage(img.getImage());
```

Also checkout [`setIconImages()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Window.html#setIconImages-java.util.List-) which takes a `List` instead.

Comment: what should be the size of the icon?.. im gonna create one now ..

Comment: See here for interesting discussion about size: http://www.coderanch.com/t/343726/Swing-AWT-SWT-JFace/java/Frame-s-setIconImage-optimum-image

Comment: There may be different size values needed: [Sizes of frame icons used in Swing](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18224184/3453226)

Comment: You can set titlebar icon using setIconImage() of JFrame and image must be .png file

Answer (score 33):

Here is an Alternative that worked for me:

```
yourFrame.setIconImage(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage(getClass().getResource(Filepath)));
```

It's very similar to the accepted Answer.

Comment: The only one which answers how to use the image if it's a resource. :D

Comment: Example for the filepath: The image is in "myProject/res" -> `getClass().getResource("/myimage.png")` (don't forget the leading "/"!)

Answer (score 6):

`JFrame.setIconImage(Image image)` pretty standard.

Comment: These solutions do not work.

Answer (score 5):

Here is how I do it:

```
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import java.io.File;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;



public class MainFrame implements ActionListener{

/**
 * 
 */


/**
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String appdata = System.getenv("APPDATA");
    String iconPath = appdata + "\\JAPP_icon.png";
    File icon = new File(iconPath);

    if(!icon.exists()){
        FileDownloaderNEW fd = new FileDownloaderNEW();
        fd.download("http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/artua/mac/512/Setting-icon.png", iconPath, false, false);
    }
        JFrame frm = new JFrame("Test");
        ImageIcon imgicon = new ImageIcon(iconPath);
        JButton bttn = new JButton("Kill");
        MainFrame frame = new MainFrame();
        bttn.addActionListener(frame);
        frm.add(bttn);
        frm.setIconImage(imgicon.getImage());
        frm.setSize(100, 100);
        frm.setVisible(true);


}

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    System.exit(0);

}

}
```

and here is the downloader:

```
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.BufferedOutputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;

import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JProgressBar;

public class FileDownloaderNEW extends JFrame {
  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

  public static void download(String a1, String a2, boolean showUI, boolean exit)
    throws Exception
  {

    String site = a1;
    String filename = a2;
    JFrame frm = new JFrame("Download Progress");
    JProgressBar current = new JProgressBar(0, 100);
    JProgressBar DownloadProg = new JProgressBar(0, 100);
    JLabel downloadSize = new JLabel();
    current.setSize(50, 50);
    current.setValue(43);
    current.setStringPainted(true);
    frm.add(downloadSize);
    frm.add(current);
    frm.add(DownloadProg);
    frm.setVisible(showUI);
    frm.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 3, 5, 5));
    frm.pack();
    frm.setDefaultCloseOperation(3);
    try
    {
      URL url = new URL(site);
      HttpURLConnection connection = 
        (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
      int filesize = connection.getContentLength();
      float totalDataRead = 0.0F;
      BufferedInputStream in = new      BufferedInputStream(connection.getInputStream());
      FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(filename);
      BufferedOutputStream bout = new BufferedOutputStream(fos, 1024);
      byte[] data = new byte[1024];
      int i = 0;
      while ((i = in.read(data, 0, 1024)) >= 0)
      {
        totalDataRead += i;
        float prog = 100.0F - totalDataRead * 100.0F / filesize;
        DownloadProg.setValue((int)prog);
        bout.write(data, 0, i);
        float Percent = totalDataRead * 100.0F / filesize;
        current.setValue((int)Percent);
        double kbSize = filesize / 1000;

        String unit = "kb";
        double Size;
        if (kbSize > 999.0D) {
          Size = kbSize / 1000.0D;
          unit = "mb";
        } else {
          Size = kbSize;
        }
        downloadSize.setText("Filesize: " + Double.toString(Size) + unit);
      }
      bout.close();
      in.close();
      System.out.println("Took " + System.nanoTime() / 1000000000L / 10000L + "      seconds");
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
      JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(
        null, e.getMessage(), "Error", 
        -1);
    } finally {
        if(exit = true){
            System.exit(128);   
        }

    }
  }
}
```

Comment: `imgicon.getImage()` is what i needed thanks

Answer (score 4):

Just add the following code:

```
setIconImage(new ImageIcon(PathOfFile).getImage());
```

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, the above solution did not work for Jython Fiji plugin. I had to use **getProperty** to construct the relative path dynamically.

Here's what worked for me:

```
import java.lang.System.getProperty;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;

frame = JFrame("Test")
icon = ImageIcon(getProperty('fiji.dir') + '/path/relative2Fiji/icon.png')
frame.setIconImage(icon.getImage());
frame.setVisible(True)
```

Comment: what is jthon? @otterb

Comment: Jython is Python implemented with java

Answer (score 1):

This did the trick in my case `super` or `this` referes to `JFrame` in my class

```
URL url = getClass().getResource("gfx/hi_20px.png");
ImageIcon imgicon = new ImageIcon(url);
super.setIconImage(imgicon.getImage());
```

Comment: You don't need the super or this in your case. You can leave it out.

Comment: may be you are right it depends on your inheritance design

Comment: If you extend your class it is not really necessary.

Comment: as i remember i think i had inner classes with same method which make thing ambigous but yor assumption is the default i agree

Comment: Yes you are right. That is why I said it's not necessary, because it has to be done sometimes if you wan't two have a method with the same name ^^

Answer (score -1):

Add the following code within the constructor like so:

```
public Calculator() {
    initComponents();
//the code to be added        this.setIconImage(newImageIcon(getClass().getResource("color.png")).getImage());     }
```

Change "color.png" to the file name of the picture you want to insert.
Drag and drop this picture onto the package (under Source Packages) of your project.

Run your project.

Comment: You can set titlebar icon using setIconImage() of JFrame and image must be .png file