# Inserting logo in the corner of JFrame

Tags: java, swing, icons, jframe, imageicon

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to change JFrame Icon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1614772/how-to-change-jframe-icon)

I want to put Logo or some icon on the corner of window in my Java desktop application.

How to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`setIconImage(ImageIcon)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JFrame.html#setIconImage%28java.awt.Image%29) for this.

Comment: Oh, I see what you did there! :)

Comment: +1  Answers can also be edited.  ;)