# How to change the image on the taskbar button to a custom image on a Swing application?

Tags: java, image, swing, icons, imageicon

I want to be able to change the taskbar button image to a custom image instead of the default Java image.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1614772/how-to-change-jframe-icon

Answer (score 5):

Use

```
ImageIcon img = new ImageIcon(PathToFile);
frame.setIconImage(img.getImage())
```

Keep in mind if you export it to a jar it will still have the Java coffee cup as its icon.

You can also use `Window#setIconImages` which allows you to supply a variety of image sizes which allows the native windowing system to decide which one it would like to use (Thanks MadProgrammer)

Comment: You can also use [`Window#setIconImages`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Window.html#setIconImages(java.util.List)) which allows you to supply a variety of image sizes which allows the native windowing system to decide which one it would like to use...makes it look nicer ;)

Comment: @MadProgrammer nice one i didn't know about that

Comment: @MadProgrammer  Good point.  See also [Sizes of frame icons used in Swing](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18224184/418556) & the answer of [mKorbel](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18225431/418556) for a summary of preferred sizes for two Windows set-ups.

Comment: @peeskillet Raise a separate answer so I can upvote it ;)